# Is there a way to use object property shorthand in constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, shorthand

Since the normal syntax for creating an object constructor,

```
function Player(name,score){
  this.name=name;
  this.score=score;
}
```

has a lot of redundancy, I was wondering if there was a way to create it similar to the object property shorthand. Something like:

```
function Player(name,score){
  this.name;
  this.score;
}
```

Comment: Where is the redundancy?

Comment: @mahatmanich Having to type "`name`" thrice.

Comment: You could write function Player(a,b) { this.name=a; this.score=b;}

Comment: Closing this question and putting a TS answer to it does not really answer the question.